# How to handle routes in Flask which contains both dynamic and static components?

Tags: flask, routes

How to handle routes in Flask which contains both dynamic and static components?

I want routes like `'/<var>-some-text'`

Function definition:

```
@app.route('/<var>-some-text')
def func(var):
    return render_template('generate-var-pages.html',var=var)
```

On page load I get 404 error. I can't make routes like `'/<var>/some-text'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I treated `<var>-some-text` as a variable (say myVar) and extracted var from myVar. Fortunately, `some-text` was a constant so it was easy.

```
@app.route('/<myVar>')
def func(myVar):
    var = extract(myVar)
    return render_template('generate-var-pages.html',var=var)

def extract(myVar):
    # var = code to get var from myVar
    return var
```